# getting some attributes, others missing in query loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have a PS script that loops AD to get lastlogon attribute plus others.
I want to get the displayName, SamAccountName, whenCreated, whenChanged, distinguishedname and last logontime.
Now it all works fine except the output CSV is missing the displayName, whenCreated and whenChanged attributes.

I'm puzzeled that it works for some attributes and not others.

Here's my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

function Get-ADUsersLastLogon() {
  $dcs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter {Name -like "*"}
  $users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=Other Users,ou=Users,ou=Items,dc=mydc,dc=,dc=com"
  $time = 0
  $exportFilePath = "c:\tmp\lastLogon $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy).csv"
  $columns = "name;username;whencreated;whenchanged;DNname;datetime"

  Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Force -InputObject $columns

  foreach ($user in $users) {
    foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
      $hostname = $dc.HostName
      $currentUser = Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName |
                     Get-ADObject -Server $hostname -Properties lastLogon

      if ($currentUser.LastLogon -gt $time) {
        $time = $currentUser.LastLogon
      }
    }

    $dt = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($time)
    $row = $user.displayName + ";" + $user.SamAccountName + ";" +
           $user.whenCreated + ";" + $user.whenChanged + ";" +
           $user.distinguishedName + ";" + $dt

    Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Append -NoClobber -InputObject $row

    $time = 0
  }
}

Get-ADUsersLastLogon
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "..."` -> `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "..." -Property DisplayName, WhenCreated, WhenChanged`. AD cmdlets by default return only a subset of all available attributes.

Comment: Oh wow, many thanks Ansgar for your reply, it worked. I thought putting it in my loop would read it as I didn't want to read each time on each DC. Very happy with your solution :-) Have a great day :-)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think `-Property` should be `-Properties` for [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Comment: @Theo Both work. If you go to the description of the parameter `-Properties` you'll find `-Property` listed as an alias.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ah, yes you're right. Never looked at the alias name..